# Using the decision problem, PATH in order to solve the optimization problem, SHORTEST-PATH in polynomial time

Tags: shortest-path, np

So, if I were using a black-box decision algorithm, `PATH` in which I could say, "does a path of weight `k` exist in this graph from `S` to `V`", problably the typical way one would solve the optimization problem of shortest path is to start at `k` at zero and increment until `PATH` returns true. But since paths start at `-inf` shouldn't we be starting there? (Thus making this optimization problem not solvable in polynomial time)

I know this isn't right, I'm just having a hard time seeing which part I am missing here.

Comment: "Since paths start at `-inf` shouldn't we be starting there?" Why should we start at `-inf`? Can you explain why we shouldn't start at 100000000 or even `+inf`?

Answer (score 2):

For non-negative weights $0$ is a lower bound and thus sufficient. For arbitrary weights you can binary search in $[l,u]$, for a lower bound $l=\sum_{a\in A\mid d_a<0} d_a$ and an upper bound $u=\sum_{a\in A\mid d_a>0} d_a$ on the length of any simple path.